# How can I clone a keyspace to another DSE cluster?

Tags: cassandra, datastax-enterprise

I have a question about Cassandra Backup & Restore procedure.

I have setup a 3-node source cluster and now I took a backup of a keyspace using: https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/6.8/dse-admin/datastax_enterprise/operations/opsBackupRestoreManaging.html

Now I copied all the backups from three nodes and trying to restore on the target 3-node Cassandra cluster using: https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/6.8/dse-admin/datastax_enterprise/operations/opsBackupRestoreRestoring.html

But it doesn't allow us to restore keyspace from the different cluster, could you please direct or recommend how I can create a copy or clone of source cluster?

Comment: I may not be reading your question correctly, but I will comment that you can't restore the keyspace to a different cluster with a different cluster_name in cassandra.yaml. If I am mis-reading the question, feel free to ignore. :)

Comment: Sorry for the delay in responses -- the Cassandra community were in New Orleans last week for ApacheCon. I myself am flying home back to Australia today so we will get back to you with an answer as soon as we can. Thanks for being part of our community. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

For clarification, the [Backup & Restore Service](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/6.8/dse-admin/datastax_enterprise/operations/opsBackupRestoreServiceAbout.html) is an enterprise feature only available in [DataStax Enterprise](https://www.datastax.com/products/datastax-enterprise) (DSE). It is not a feature that is available in open-source Apache Cassandra and I just wanted to make that distinction clear so there's no confusion.

Having said all that, it is possible to clone a keyspace from one DSE cluster to another provided they were configured correctly.

You haven't provided any details on how you've configured both the source DSE cluster and the destination DSE cluster so it's impossible for me to comment on why you're having issues. Ideally, you need to update your post above with additional details most importantly the steps to replicate the issue you're running into. Cheers!